# How are antibodies specific for a disease detected in the blood if everybody produces a different antibody for the same antigen?

Tags: microbiology, immunology, immune-system, antibody, antigen

To break the title down into parts:

- There exist serology tests that detect the amount of an antibody (Ab)
  against a specific pathogen/antigen.
- Every human produces their own Ab for a specific antigen by
  (relatively) random combination of different gene segments in their B
  cells, until one that recognizes the pathogen is found and produced
  in massive amounts.
- One portion of every Ab is constant, whereas the portion that
  recognizes the antigen is variable. Even for antibodies (in different
  humans) that recognize the same antigen, albeit to a lesser degree.

What exactly does an antibody titer/serology test detect in the blood so that it can accurately measure the amount of antibodies against a specific antigen? I am assuming they use antibodies against the antigen-binding/variable portion of an antibody. But if the variable region differs from person to person, how can a universal antibody (to be used in serology tests) against it be generated?

Is the variable region not *that* variable, so that any lab-generated antibody against any functional antibody against a virus works well enough for an accurate measurement of antibodies against that virus? But even so the concept sounds hard to believe since even a single antigen can have multiple epitopes, and one person might have an Ab for epitope 1 of antigen X, while the other would have an Ab for epitope 2 of antigen X. And they would still be immune to the same virus, while a universal Ab titer test for the virus would be unable to detect antibodies from one of them.

Do they perhaps employ multiple lab-generated antibodies against most of the possible variations of human-generated antibodies in the tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specific antibodies are typically detected using [ELISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELISA).

The way you make a test for an antibody to a particular pathogen is not by using secondary antibodies to the specific part of the target antibody, but by **using the antigen**.

Different kits work differently, but the general idea is that you have antigen stuck to a surface, you put the sample on that surface. If there are antibodies to the antigen, they stick to it. Then you wash everything away and add a tagged antibody that binds to generic human antibodies.

See also https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2020/03/new-blood-tests-antibodies-could-show-true-scale-coronavirus-pandemic

Comment: ohh, using an antigen-coated surface makes a whole lot more sense. I don't know why I had such an extreme roundabout way of thinking.